# Insert only if entry doesn't exit

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, insert

In my Android app i download a JSON file, i parse it and i write every entry of the JSONObject to local SQLite database. Here is my code:

```
public void myMethod() {
        JSONArray myJA = connectAndCreateJsonArray(url);
        localDB.beginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) myJA.getJSONObject(i);
            localDB.insert("users", null, getParsedMerchantEntry(jObj));
        }

        localDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
```

Here is the body of connectAndCreateJsonArray():

```
    private JSONArray connectAndCreateJsonArray(String url) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {   
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Here is the body of getParsedMerchantEntry():

```
    private ContentValues getParsedMerchantEntry(JSONObject entry) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("id", entry.optString("id").toString());
        values.put("city", entry.optString("city").toString());
        values.put("name", entry.optString("firstname").toString());
        values.put("surname", entry.optString("lastname").toString());

        return values;
    }
```

Any way to avoid to call localDB.insert() if that entry already exist in local database?

Comment: Doing a query on the `id` before inserting shouldn't add much overhead

Comment: You could also just try the insert and catch, but ignore the failure if the ID already exists.  That way you're not reading just to turn around and write.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle this using query

Here is the sample way.

```
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put("id", qclass);
insertValues.put("question", question);

yourDbName.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE, null, insertValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Make sure your Id field is create as not null and unique.